# htaccess RewriteRule regular expression for url with any nesting

Tags: apache-http-server, regex, htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is a site `example.com/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/.../zzzz`, where `/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/.../zzzz` is a path with any nesting.

If the URL contains a file or directory starting with a dot (hidden file or directory) and this file/directory exists, then do a 301 redirect to `example.com/1`.

If the file does not exist, then redirect to to `example.com/2`

Prompt at least a regular expression for such a URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]/\.[^/]/) forbidden [R=301]
```

I tried to come up with a regular expression, which if the URL contains a hidden file / directory, then a redirect would go through. But it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using mod_rewrite near the top of the root `.htaccess` file.  For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Skip the next 2 rules if the requested URL does "not" match
# ie. A dot/hidden file or directory has "NOT" been requested
RewriteRule !(^|/)\.[^/]+ - [S=2]

# If the request for a hidden file/dir exists then redirect to "/1"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ /1 [R=301,L]

# If the request for a hidden file/dir does "NOT" exist then redirect to "/2"
RewriteRule ^ /2 [R=301,L]
```

The regex `(^|/)\.[^/]+` matches any URL-path where *any* path-segment starts with a dot (to catch the scenario of requesting a file in a "hidden" directory).

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]/\.[^/]/) forbidden [R=301]
> ```

The regex used here would only match URLs of the form `/<single-character/.<single-character>/<anything>` - where the "hidden" file/directory exists only in the 2nd path-segment and is only 1 character in length. It also doesn't check the existence of that file/directory. And the rule is missing the `L` flag, so processing continues (and a redirect may not occur or would be malformed, depending on directives that followed).